# Remove greater-than (>) character highlight in gVIM, it's a template file, not HTML

Tags: php, vim, laravel-blade

I want to remove the highlight of the '>' character. Those arrows are PHP arrows inside a Blade template file. Please help.

[image: caracter greater-than highlight]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unencoded `>` in HTML is an error, that's why it's red.

Write the correct form, `&gt;`, and the highlight will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not a HTML file though, it's a Blade file. Blade's a template language, and those arrows (`->`) are PHP arrows. How do I tell Vim that?

Comment: You need to download the Blade syntax file. Maybe this one works? https://github.com/jwalton512/vim-blade

Comment: Thanks. I did install that plugin, but no change. Searched for other syntax plugins for blade with no success. It seems like its a plugin bug. https://github.com/jwalton512/vim-blade/issues/68

Comment: Are you sure the file is being loaded at all? For all I can see, the file is *.php, the editor probably picks the wrong syntax based on the file extension.

Comment: You were right, it wasn't reading the plugin; I hadn't `syntax on` in my `.vimrc` file. Thanks man, cheers. <3 <3